# Open web view through map view pinpoints; Xcode

Tags: android, ios, webview, annotations, android-mapview

I have a map view with several pinpoints which I have in a plist. When i click the pin I have a button that launches a website with safari. I want to change this to open the website in web view so I can add a back button to return to the application. Anyone knows how to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: What problems are you facing while doing this?

Comment: It works fine now, but i can´t return to the application after being linked to one of the websites.

Comment: Then create a view controller that has a webview and push it when the button is pressed instead of launching the safari app with the predefined url.

Comment: I tried to add the code but it did't work

Comment: Yes, I tried to do that but I'm not skilled in programming so I did't get it to work...

Comment: So an example would be very appreciated. :-)

Comment: @AntonHjertén, you should post the code that you tried (edit the question and add it) and explain exactly how "it didn't work" (exact text of compiler warning/error/crash/etc).